# WPF : troubleshooting application with occassional high CPU utilization on Win 7 64 using WinDbg

Tags: wpf, windbg, windows-7-x64

I have a .NET 3.5 WPF applicaiton that will occassionalyly utilize 96-99% of CPU time when running only on Win 7 64 bit.  Of course when this happens, even the application itself stops working correctly.  This is another issue that happens only on the 64 bit version of Windows 7.

The application is currently in this state and I will like to use WinDbg or some other debugging tool to capture as much information as possible.  Anyone online who can help with this in real time?

First off, this is what I can get from Process Explorer:  As the attached image shows [image], I have a thread count of 40 with a bunch of them having start address:

```
mscorwrks.dll!GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x934c.
```

There are about 24 threads currently showing this as the start address.   But I cannot relate this to anything in my code.

So I am currently attached to the process using WinDbg, which has suspended all threads. Then I did

```
!runaway 3
```

which gives me:

```
0:039> !runaway 3
 User Mode Time
  Thread       Time
  33:29bc      0 days 0:27:48.711
  21:2880      0 days 0:26:22.021
  34:18cc      0 days 0:24:38.873
  18:2a04      0 days 0:23:56.753
  23:2618      0 days 0:18:58.947
  24:27e8      0 days 0:17:36.859
  30:21d4      0 days 0:17:05.800
  32:248c      0 days 0:17:04.286
  35:2b00      0 days 0:16:20.809
  22:2680      0 days 0:15:37.597
   5:2a28      0 days 0:15:10.234
  31:ee4       0 days 0:15:07.348
  20:20f0      0 days 0:14:32.903
  17:29ac      0 days 0:14:02.202
  10:20dc      0 days 0:00:51.152
  11:2ad0      0 days 0:00:11.247
  37:2c14      0 days 0:00:06.489
  38:2f3c      0 days 0:00:01.466
  25:1db8      0 days 0:00:00.920
   1:2a84      0 days 0:00:00.452
   0:1494      0 days 0:00:00.093
   2:1ba0      0 days 0:00:00.078
  29:53c       0 days 0:00:00.015
  27:278c      0 days 0:00:00.015
   7:8d4       0 days 0:00:00.015
   4:2620      0 days 0:00:00.015
  39:215c      0 days 0:00:00.000
  36:2088      0 days 0:00:00.000
  28:26e0      0 days 0:00:00.000
  26:2960      0 days 0:00:00.000
  19:2a10      0 days 0:00:00.000
  16:2a70      0 days 0:00:00.000
  15:24a8      0 days 0:00:00.000
  14:2208      0 days 0:00:00.000
  13:2bcc      0 days 0:00:00.000
  12:2a6c      0 days 0:00:00.000
   9:1a38      0 days 0:00:00.000
   8:2a98      0 days 0:00:00.000
   6:1200      0 days 0:00:00.000
   3:2af8      0 days 0:00:00.000
 Kernel Mode Time
  Thread       Time
  11:2ad0      0 days 0:00:03.650
  10:20dc      0 days 0:00:02.230
  33:29bc      0 days 0:00:00.686
  34:18cc      0 days 0:00:00.577
  21:2880      0 days 0:00:00.327
  18:2a04      0 days 0:00:00.327
  24:27e8      0 days 0:00:00.280
  35:2b00      0 days 0:00:00.249
   1:2a84      0 days 0:00:00.218
  30:21d4      0 days 0:00:00.156
  22:2680      0 days 0:00:00.140
   5:2a28      0 days 0:00:00.140
  37:2c14      0 days 0:00:00.124
  23:2618      0 days 0:00:00.109
   2:1ba0      0 days 0:00:00.109
  25:1db8      0 days 0:00:00.093
  20:20f0      0 days 0:00:00.093
  17:29ac      0 days 0:00:00.093
   0:1494      0 days 0:00:00.078
   7:8d4       0 days 0:00:00.062
  32:248c      0 days 0:00:00.046
   3:2af8      0 days 0:00:00.046
  31:ee4       0 days 0:00:00.031
   8:2a98      0 days 0:00:00.031
  38:2f3c      0 days 0:00:00.015
  27:278c      0 days 0:00:00.015
  16:2a70      0 days 0:00:00.015
  15:24a8      0 days 0:00:00.015
  39:215c      0 days 0:00:00.000
  36:2088      0 days 0:00:00.000
  29:53c       0 days 0:00:00.000
  28:26e0      0 days 0:00:00.000
  26:2960      0 days 0:00:00.000
  19:2a10      0 days 0:00:00.000
  14:2208      0 days 0:00:00.000
  13:2bcc      0 days 0:00:00.000
  12:2a6c      0 days 0:00:00.000
   9:1a38      0 days 0:00:00.000
   6:1200      0 days 0:00:00.000
   4:2620      0 days 0:00:00.000
```

When I issue `g` to continue the process, I get

```
0:039> g
(2944.1d6c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
mscorlib_ni+0x367240:
000007fe`f8337240 cc              int     3
```

and process remains suspended.  How do I continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to fix your symbols. After you attach windbg, do the following:

.symopt+0x100;.symfix c:\websym;.reload

My guess is that thread 39 is the injected debugger thread so it's ok to get that break instruction once after hitting g. If you get it more than once then there's a problem.

But before hitting g, switch to the first thread (33 in your case) in the !runaway output like this:
~33s

Then load the correct .NET debugger extension dll. If prior to .NET 4, do:

.loadby sos.dll mscorwks

If .NET 4 and later do:

.loadby sos.dll clr

Now do this to see the managed stack:

!clrstack

Then hit g, let it run for a few seconds, break into again, then issue !clrstack again. Repeat several times to give you an idea of what thread 33 is doing. Note, each time you break you'll have to switch back to thread 33 before issuing !clrstack.

If no managed stack is displayed, then issue kb to see the native stack.

You may also want to see if you have managed exceptions for that thread. !pe will do that for you (after you switch to that thread). You can also dump all managed exception objects. I think the command is !dumpallexceptions but check the help (using !help) to be certain. Note, .NET preallocates 3 exception objects at startup that can (most of the time) be ignored in the !dumpallexceptions output (one has to do with out-of-memory situations).

Marc

Answer (score 0):

I think the clr exceptions are what that is stopping you from continuing the process. 
Suppress those exceptions with "sxi clr" and continue

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick is to capture a group of hang dumps (one minute interval) when CPU usage is high, and then analyze them in WinDbg. Using runaway you can see which threads consume most of CPU and then check its call stack to locate the possible cause.

What you did is called live debug, and it is not easy for a beginner.